# How to create temp files in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to attach an xml file and send as email. I have a string of text which I want to write in an xml file. But I don't want to actually create a file every time.

I am using nodemailer(https://community.nodemailer.com/using-attachments/) to send mail and it supports stream to attach file.

Does stream mean it has to actually create a file? Can't I just use stream somehow to send it as an attachment without creating a file.

I have xml string like this which I want to put in an xml file and send email:

```
    const xmlStringStart = `<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
  <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
  <IMPORTDATA>
    <REQUESTDESC>
      <REPORTNAME>All Masters</REPORTNAME>
      <STATICVARIABLES>
        <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>X</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
      </STATICVARIABLES>
    </REQUESTDESC>
    <REQUESTDATA>...`;
```

I saw PassThrough https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough but can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the nodemailer document, you can use an utf-8 string as an attachment :

```
   attachments: [ {   // utf-8 string as an attachment
            filename: 'text1.txt',
            content: xmlStringStart // your string
        },
   ]
```

I think this is simpler and better in your case. The stream option is like, reading the file as a stream then put the content to the attachment.

Comment: i want xml file. will this be valid if i give filename as text1.xml

Comment: Although it isn't noted in the document, I strongly believe that you can put .XML as the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer it if I could have a code example to work on, but the basic concept remains the same.

You can just create a file, send it as an attachment through nodemailer, and then delete the file once that action is complete, thus making it act like a temporary file.

```
//create a txt file and write Hello World into it
fs.writeFileSync("/foo/bar.txt", "Hello World")

/*
Send file as attachment to nodemailer
*/

//once you're done sending file, go ahead and delete it
fs.unlink("/foo/bar.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the filename here refers to the displayed filename as its downloaded as attachment. the path option is the file location..

as for passthrough.. it's probably like

```
const pt = new PassThrough();
{   // stream as an attachment
    filename: 'text4.txt',
    content: pt
},

then 
pt.write("....");
to close: pt.end("..."()
```